# Can you convert a metric hole into sae tap?

Tags: drill, hole, bolts

I tapped an m11 x 1.5 hole in my car frame to mount the hitch... now can {can't} find a matching bolt and i cant go much bigger
Ive read that 7/16 is pretty close just wondering possibilities

Can you retap an sae into a metric bolt?
Or 
Retapping my frame with 7/16?

Thanks
Yann

Comment: My first thought is to keep looking for the M11 x 1.5 bolt you need. How long? Of course, for a trailer hitch it has to be out of a steel that is rated for this application. http://advrider.com/index.php?threads/source-for-m11-x-1-5-bolt.571924/ They recommend Metrics Unlimited http://www.metricsunlimited.com/

Comment: Agree w/ @JimStewart . It's really not hard to find the bolt you need, and re-tapping will only work if you go to a significantly larger hole size.

Comment: Cant get it anywhere in my area fond some flywheel bolt for 10$ a piece.. too expensive and too long for me , i need between an inch and inch and half long